# Does Stepanov's method extend to complete intersections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, weil-conjectures

Stepanov (circa 1970) created the polynomial method to limit the rational points of an algebraic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$, leading to one of several alternative proofs of Weil's Riemann hypothesis for one-dimensional function fields. The essence of Stepanov's method is succinctly demonstrated on a genus one curve in section 1.6 of Baker and Wustholz's *Logarithmic Forms in Diophantine Geometry* (emphasizing its affinity with the methodology of transcendence theory), and the general case is given by Bombieri in the [Bourbaki Seminar](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1972-1973__15_/SB_1972-1973__15__234_0/SB_1972-1973__15__234_0.pdf) and exposed in [Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/the-bombieri-stepanov-proof-of-the-hasse-weil-bound/).

Deligne's higher dimensional theorem on the purity of Frobenius eigenvalues on cohomology does not in general admit an interpretation by limiting the rational points of an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$; the Lang-Weil bound $|X(\mathbb{F}_q) - q^{\dim{X}}| = O_X(q^{\dim{X}-1/2})$ (as $q$ varies) is in general sharp, due to the presence of $(2\dim{X}-1)$-dimensional cohomology, and lies no deeper than the one-dimensional case, from which it was originally derived.

But suppose $X \subset \mathbb{P}_{/\mathbb{F}_q}^N$ is a smooth complete intersection. In that case, Theoreme 8.1 in Deligne's "Weil I" yields
$$
|X(\mathbb{F}_q)| \leq |\mathbb{P}^{\dim{X}}(\mathbb{F}_q)| + O(q^{{\dim{X}}/2}),
$$
with an implied constant only depending on $\deg{X}$. (It is in fact an equality, but let me only ask about limiting the $\mathbb{F}_q$-points since this is what Stepanov's method does.)

**The question.** *Has Stepanov's polynomial method (or another "elementary approach") been attempted in such a higher dimensional situation?*

Comment: My understanding is that elementary methods usually have difficulty taking advantage of smoothness, but that's not a guarantee...

Comment: Wofgang Schmidt has considered Stepanov's method in higher dimensions but doesn't get what Deligne does. See, for example, his book "Equations over finite fields. An elementary approach", SLNM, 536.